# iOS 11 JavaScript can't find variable `globalThis`

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari, this

Is there a chance that [JavaScript globalThis](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_globalthis) is not supported to be used with an iOS 11, or earlier versions?

Is there any solution to the globalThis, since now, I get an error for `ReferenceError: main.chunk.js Can't find variable: globalThis`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MDN page on globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#Browser_compatibility), iOS Safari support is version 12.2 or later.

For earlier versions, you will need a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalthis).

Or you could insert this code at the **global** context:

```js
if (typeof globalThis === 'undefined') {
  var globalThis = Function('return this')();
}
```

Comment: As of today, per the link, they state "12.1" as the first supported version. It's also according to my tests, that Apple devices with macOS Mojave (Safari 12.1.2) or newer support global this.